# No puedo convertir un string que proviene de un TextField a un entero en React Javascrip

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

tengo un problema creando una app web que calculara las notas, he utilizado el siguiente codigo

```
<form>
          <TextField
            name='corte1'
            type='number'
            label='Nota del primer corte'
            sx={{ m: 1 }}
            size='small'
            onChange={(e) => setNot1(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          />
          <br></br>

          <TextField
            name='corte2'
            type='number'
            label='Nota del segundo corte'
            sx={{ m: 1 }}
            size='small'
            onChange={(e) => setNot2(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          />
          <br></br>

          <TextField 
            name='corte3'
            type='number'
            label='Nota del tercer corte'
            sx={{ m: 1 }}
            size='small'
            onChange={(e) => setNot3(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          />
          <br></br>

          <Button
            sx={{ m: 2 }}
            variant='contained'
            onClick={() => { calcular3 }}
          >
            Calcular
          </Button>
        </form>
```

y la funcion a la que llamo durante el onClick es esta:

```
function calcular3(){
    setNotaFinal((not1*0.3)+(not2*0.3)+(not3*0.4))
    if(notaFinal > 9.6){
      setAprobado(true)
    }else{
      <p>Tu calificacion no es suficiente para aprobar</p>
    }
  }
```

tambie declare los estados de  `const [not1, setNot1] = useState(0) const [not2, setNot2] = useState(0) const [not3, setNot3] = useState(0)`

supongo que no se actualiza el valor del estado notaFinal ya que por alguna razon no se hacen las operaciones porque no le llegan los numeros como enteros a la funcion, agradeceria cualquier ayuda

Comment: Creo que el error es este `onClick={() => { calcular3 }}`, debería ser `onClick={() => { calcular3() }}` o también prueba con `onClick={calcular3}`.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, en la funcion `calcular3`, al inicio aplicas el set del estado `notaFinal`  en `setNotaFinal((not1*0.3)+(not2*0.3)+(not3*0.4))` y luego hay un condicional `if(notaFinal > 9.6){...}` dentro de ese condicional ¿Esperas que `notaFinal` haya cambiado su valor debido al set que realizaste al inicio?

Comment: Hola! si, ahi esperaria que se evalue el if con el valor que recien se le dio

Comment: bien, tengo curiosidad por el componente `TextField`,  ¿Tienes el código del componente `TextField` o estas usandolo por medio de alguna libreria? Si tienes el código compartelo ...

Comment: Hola, si, el componente textField es de la libreria de MaterialUI